# UiTableview cell scaling animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

Hi I am new to IOS devlopment.I need my table view cell to animate like scaling animation(i. e.whenever I scroll up, the cell size need to scale out (increase) from center position based on scrolling position and whenever I scroll down the cell size  should scale in(decrease) based on scrolling position).I tried to find but I can't able to trigger out the actual solution.Can anyone help me out regarding this.Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: do you have any video/gif file to show us ?

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uNnKp.gif

Comment: The easiest way would be adding a view to cell contentView and animating it right before you load your cell on screen!

Comment: Please look at the above link

Comment: I tried it also but it haven't worked For me

Comment: Please provide details of what you have tried and highlight what didn't work for you.

Comment: I tried this code in willDisplay cell  delegate method in which it is scaling but I need to scaling from center position

cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0.5);
    // define final state (e.g. after animation) & commit animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"scaleTableViewCellAnimationID" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    cell.alpha = 1;
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114130/discussion-between-venkat-09-and-teja-nandamuri).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to animate the `UIImageView` in `UITableViewCell`. This is just an idea, You can change it as per your requirement.

Write the Following code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
cell.animatedImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:(void (^)(void)) ^{
                     cell.animatedImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){


                     if (finished) {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                               delay:0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                          animations:(void (^)(void)) ^{
                                              cell.animatedImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              cell.animatedImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                                          }];
                     }

                 }];
```

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Thanks for ur idea.I tried it but according to your code the cell will perform scaling once the cell is allocated but for me the scaling out and scaling in should perform based on scrolling of the tableview even though the cell is allocated.

Comment: @Venkat_09 from the above code animation will start from beginning on each and every time when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` fire. So when you start scrolling, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be fire and animation will start from the beginning.

Comment: i need animation similar to depth page animation effect in android

Comment: I need animation similar to washington post app(blue app icon)listing screen table view animation

Comment: @Venkat_09 try this above solution in prepareForReuse of your custom cell. this way the animation will be performed every time the cell is reused. Let me know your result.